# Difference between interior and set of accumulation points

Tags: general-topology

I don't understand the difference between the interior of a set, and the set of all its accumulation points.

My understanding of an accumulation point is any point in a set which has an epsilon neighborhood around it, which is contained in the set- not necessarily implying that the accumulation point itself is in the set.

From what I can gather, the interior is identical. Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: If $N$ is a nbhd of $x$, then by definition $x\in N$, so if $N\subseteq A$, then $x\in A$: if a nbhd of $x$ is contained in the set $A$, then necessarily $x$ belongs to the set $A$.

Comment: not necessarily? for example, in the set [0,2]\ {1}, 1 is an accumulation point but is not contained in the set.

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with my assertion. I did not say that an accumulation point of $A$ is necessarily in $A$; that is of course false. I said that if $x$ is in the interior of $A$, then $x$ is necessarily in $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no necessary relationship between the two sets.

Let $A$ be a set in a topological space $X$. A point $x$ is in the interior of $A$ if there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U\subseteq A$; in particular this implies that $x\in A$. A point $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if for each open set $U$ containing $x$, $U\cap(A\setminus\{x\}\ne\varnothing$; in words, if every open nbhd of $x$ contains at least one point of $A$ different from $x$. This does not imply that $x\in A$.

Take the space $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology as a familiar example. The set $\Bbb Z$ has empty interior: for any $n\in\Bbb Z$, no matter how small an $\epsilon>0$ you take, $(n-\epsilon,n+\epsilon)\nsubseteq\Bbb Z$, so $n$ is not in the interior of $\Bbb Z$. $\Bbb Z$ also has no accumulation points: if $x\in\Bbb R\setminus Z$, there is an integer $n$ such that $n<x<n+1$, and $(n,n+1)$ is then an open nbhd of $n$ that contains no point of $\Bbb Z$; and if $n\in\Bbb Z$, $(n-1,n+1)$ is an open nbhd of $n$ that contains no point of $\Bbb Z\setminus\{n\}$. In this case the interior of the set is its set of accumulation points: each is the empty set, $\varnothing$. But now consider the following sets:

- The set $\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$, on the other hand, has empty interior and exactly one accumulation point, $0$.
- $\Bbb Q$ also has empty interior, and **every** real number is an accumulation point of $\Bbb Q$.
- $[0,1]$, $[0,1)$, and $(0,1)$ all have interior $(0,1)$, and all have $[0,1]$ as their set of accumulation points.

(In each case you should try to prove the assertions.)

If we look at $\Bbb Z$ as a space in its own right, with the discrete topology, then every subset of $\Bbb Z$ is open, and no point of $\Bbb Z$ is an accumulation point of any subset of $\Bbb Z$. Thus, if $A\subseteq\Bbb Z$, then the interior of $A$ is $A$ itself, but $A$ has no accumulation points.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're working with subsets of the real line with the usual topology.

The definition you gave for accumulation point is actually the definition for interior point, and it *does* imply that the point lies in the set. Indeed, an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of a point $x$ is an interval of the form $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon>0,$ and $x$ readily lies in any such interval, so $x$ lies in any set that contains such an interval.

We say that a point $x$ is an accumulation point of a set $A$ if *every* $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ at a point distinct from $x$. This does *not* mean that every epsilon neighborhood of $x$ is contained in $A$--it's possible that *no* $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ is contained in $A,$ which means that accumulation points need not be interior points.

For an example to see that the interior and set of accumulation points are not the same, consider $[0,2]\setminus\{1\}$. The interior of the set is $(0,1)\cup(1,2),$ but the set of accumulation points is $[0,2]$. The point $1$ is an example of a non-interior accumulation point.

For another example, consider the set $\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}.$ No point of this set has a neighborhood contained in the set, so the interior is empty, but it can be shown that $0$ is the unique accumulation point. So, even if an accumulation point is *in* the set, it need not be an interior point.